# Using the Material Design package for Angular2

Tags: npm, angular, material-design

According to the angular/material2 [site](https://github.com/angular/material2), component packages can be installed with commands like `npm install @angular2-material/checkbox`.

When I used this command, the @angular2-material/checkbox folder doesn't have a checkbox.ts file for the checkbox element. Instead, it has a checkbox.d.ts file that declares a regular class named `MdCheckbox`. This isn't a component, so I can't access it in my Angular2 template.

When I download the full angular/material2 archive, the src folder contains checkbox.ts, which defines `MdCheckbox` as a component. So is there a problem with the npm package or the GitHub archive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no there is no problems in it. The `checkbox.d.ts` file isn't a component file. It's just a `declaration file`. The actual file that has the component is `checkbox.js`, it's already been transpiled to javascript.

In order to use it, "assuming you have SystemJS as your module loader, which is the default". In your index.html

```
  System.config({
    map:{
      '@angular2-material/checkbox':'node_modules/@angular2-material/checkbox'
    },
    packages: {
      '@angular2-material/checkbox': {
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: 'checkbox.js'
      },
      app:{...}
    }
  });
```

And then, in your component:

```
import {MdCheckbox} from '@angular2-material/checkbox';
```

Comment: I tried compiling with @angular2-material/checkbox, but I got a "error TS1110: Type expected." Are there any example projects that use the declaration files?

Comment: @user934904 The declaration files are used usually by your IDE. Why do you mean by  "compiling with @angular2-material/checkbox"  do you mean `import {MdCheckbox} from '@angular2-material/checkbox';` ?

Comment: @user934904 I was able to produce the issue you mentioned. It's on  `checkbox.d.ts` line 22: `align: 'start' | 'end';` It's just a typo _probably_ and should not prevent the files from compiling to javascript.